# how to use begin transaction for multiple queries and different tables (sqlite3, python)

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using the following code in order to insert data in 2 tables:

1. Variations
2. Var_entity

---

```
    #begin transaction
    cur.execute("begin")
    id_var = 0
    for red in prop_redirect["results"]["bindings"]:
        var_res = red["x"]["value"].split('/')[-1]
        var_type = "t1"
        #insert data in table VARIATIONS
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO VARIATIONS (ID, NAME, TYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (str(id_var) + "_" + str(ID), var_res, var_type))
        #insert data in table VAR_ENTITY
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO VAR_ENTITY(ID_ENTITY, ID_VAR, LANGUAGE) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", (str(ID), str(id_var) + "_" + str(ID), "en" ) )
        id_var = id_var + 1 
    #commit after for loop
    cur.execute("commit")
```

---

From what I understood, using "begin transaction" and "commit" allows a faster access to the database [Bulk insert huge data into SQLite using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219779/bulk-insert-huge-data-into-sqlite-using-python)

---

Are the `cur.execute("begin")` and `cur.execute("commit")` statements placed correctly?

---

Previous questions that I found on stackoverflow:

- [Importing a CSV file into a sqlite3 database table using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887878/importing-a-csv-file-into-a-sqlite3-database-table-using-python/2888042#2888042)
- [how to prepogate transaction for multiple request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238836/how-to-prepogate-transaction-for-multiple-request)

Comment: Please check the indentation of your code. It might be correct but as it is, it's hard to tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the statements are at the same level as the `for`, then they are at the correct place but you also need to set the `isolation_level` to something else than `None` or the driver will do a commit every time you call `cur.execute()`.

You also shouldn't use `cur.execute("commit")` but `conn.commit()` so the driver can notice what you're doing.

The `begin` isn't really necessary either. The database will automatically start a transaction for you if there isn't one, yet. So this would be better:

```
conn.isolation_level = '...' # anything but none
with conn: # let the driver handle transaction management
   cur = conn.cursor()
   for ...
       cur.execute(...)
```

Comment: isolation_level = “DEFERRED”, “IMMEDIATE” or “EXCLUSIVE. I have to check the meaning of these. But any of them will make the driver not commit everytime i call cur.execute()